# JPA EntityManager and JavaFx

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, javafx, entitymanager

I tried to use EntityManager in a JavaFx application in NetBeans (my solution is connected to postgres), I proceeded as follows :

1) I created a Persistence Unit.
2) Then Added the Entity Classes from Database.

but I can't get it to work, I tried to ask for some help in another thread [Entity Manager not working in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496448/cant-persist-using-entity-manager-in-javafx#log-in) but can't get it work either, is there any clean and clear tutorial or lesson where I can find clearly how to use a EntityManager in a JavaFx Fxml Application

Comment: Actually I had to open a new thread for that to give detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, I had to add the Postgres Driver and fix some incompatible types I was using in the database

Answer (score 1):

Well ... how does your code look like?
What is the problem?

In a JavaFX application without an application server you have to use JPA in RESOURCE_LOCAL mode. Some good info is at:

http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html

Comment: My code is just as in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496448/cant-persist-using-entity-manager-in-javafx#log-in I even made what @jewelsea said , but still not workin giving the exceptions I mentioned in the last comments, I will however try with the link you gave me and I will keep this thread updated

Comment: I verified that the transaction-type is "RESOURCE_LOCAL" tried to follow the instructions described in the link you gave me, but still getting the same error, I'm opening a new thread for this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503039/cant-create-a-entitymanager-in-javafx